# How to track Ajax actions via analytics function

Tags: javascript, ajax, decorator

I need to track a number of ajax-actions on my site and I have a `reachGoal(TARGET_NAME)` analytics function that I need insert to every function I want to track:

```
function handler_func() {
   reachGoal(TARGET_NAME);
   // Other code
   ... 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target_id').click(handler_func);
});
```

What I would like to have is to be able to manage all targets from one place, something like this:

```
handler_func.before(function() {
    reachGoal(TARGET_NAME);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a decorator function:

```
var goalReacher = function (targetName, func) { 
    return function () {
        reachGoal(targetName);
        func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};

var myCoolFunction = goalReacher("myTarget", function () {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: You mean I can also do `$('#target_id').click(goalReacher("myTarget", function() {...}));`
?